# How can I dynamically center an image in Crystal Reports?

Tags: vb.net, image, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, center

I'm using Crystal Reports in MS Visual Studio 2010 with Visual Vasic .net and I have to center an image in the report,but in the property option the alignment section is disable! Someone know why or how can I center the image? 
Or i see that have an option with css. How can I attach a CSS file or its only for ASP porjects?

I'm using Crystal Reports developer 13 for Visual Studio 2010 And the image source is form a database so, the width change in runtime.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Crystal Reports are you using?

Comment: I think it is Crystal Reports developer 13 for Visual Studio 2010 @MrCoDeXeR